# How to get rid of title "Back" for nav bar back button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar

How to get rid of title "Back" for nav bar Back button?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Nav Back Button

    UIImage *backButtonIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back_black"];

    [UINavigationBar appearance].backIndicatorImage = backButtonIcon;
    [UINavigationBar appearance].backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = backButtonIcon;

    return YES;
}
```

image [here](http://8b.kz/UlLa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UIView *backBtnView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,14,36)];
UIButton *backBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[backBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,14,36)];
[backBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImageName"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[backBtn setEnabled:YES];
[backBtnView addSubview:backBtn];
UIBarButtonItem* barbackBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backBtnView];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barbackBtn;
[backBtn addTarget:self.navigationController action:@selector(popViewControllerAnimated:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
backBtn.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
```

Comment: Please take the time and explain what you are doing here. This might not only help the OP, but everyone looking for a solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) This approach works everywhere, including on iPhone 6 Plus

Comment: mwfire, i just create absolute size frame view for my button, than i create custom btn, becouse only custom button can include image, than i paste my image, you can use your image name, for example img.png (from supported folder in your project), so as you can see first 6 lines create your custom button, next lines are for link your button to navigationController. The function initWithCustomView is the main function in this process.
[backBtn addTarget:self.navigationController action:....
this is for return to prev screen, you can reject this func

Answer (score 0):

You can set the title property of the previous viewController to an empty string, it will do the trick.

Comment: this code `self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem =
[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];` added in the _previous_ viewController and ... this way works fine everywhere, except iPhone 6 Plus only. iPhone 6 Plus has the same problem %/

Comment: Did you try in your previous view controller to do self.title = ""; in viewdidload for exemple ?

Comment: Thanks for answer, Boris ) Yes, I did. Unfortunately "the trick" doesn't work for iPhone 6 Plus (on device, not in the Simulator)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem =
[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Custom Title"
        style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
       target:nil
       action:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the back button of the previous view controller to an empty string like this.

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
[self.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem:backButtonItem];
```

But if it is a app-wide wanted behaviour then your could either do it in a base `UIViewController` subclass or do it by swizzling :)

**UIViewController+EmptyBackButton.h**

```
@interface UIViewController (EmptyBackButton)

@end
```

**UIViewController+EmptyBackButton.m**

```
#import "UIViewController+EmptyBackButton.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation UIViewController (EmptyBackButton)

+ (void)load {
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        Class class = [self class];

        SEL originalSelector = @selector(viewDidLoad);
        SEL swizzledSelector = @selector(mob_viewDidLoad);

        Method originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(class, originalSelector);
        Method swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(class, swizzledSelector);

        BOOL didAddMethod = class_addMethod(class, originalSelector, method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(swizzledMethod));

        if (didAddMethod) {
            class_replaceMethod(class, swizzledSelector, method_getImplementation(originalMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod));
        } else {
            method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod);
        }
    });
}

#pragma mark - Method Swizzling

- (void)mob_viewDidLoad {
    [self mob_viewDidLoad];
    UIBarButtonItem *backButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
    [self.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem:backButtonItem];
}

@end
```

This will add the empty back button to all subclasses of `UIViewController` in `viewDidLoad`.

Also you can have a look at a blog post I wrote a while back about [Empty Back Buttons](http://justabeech.com/2014/02/24/empty-back-button-on-ios7/).